# GitHub Pages image not showing (with proper case sensitivity and path)

Tags: github, github-pages

I recently published my gh-pages on https://yihsien1112.github.io/ and only one image is not showing even when called directly with https://yihsien1112.github.io/images/PetGo.png . The rest of the images in the images folder work just fine and I have been referencing to those images the same way in my code in index.html.

Any idea what is going on?

Link to repo: https://github.com/yihsien1112/yihsien1112.github.io

Comment: In the future, please include all relevant code in your post and [**don't** just include a link to a code hosting site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/316262). Your post should stand alone from any other resource; [consider what would happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) if that site went down in the future!

Comment: @DCCoder Sorry I am still new to stackoverflow. Thank you for the tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Somehow GitHub Pages took a little more than an hour to update it and the solution I previously tried is now working.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem earlier this week, i solved this problem by using a regular image url from the image source ( image address link ) , i hope it works with you